# Подсвечивание по умолчанию кнопок в Chrome

Tags: css

создал для тренировки вот такую страничку https://muturgan.github.io/accords/
на ней офигенно стилизовал кнопочки, в частности сделал исчезновение тени при нажатии
.myButton:active {box-shadow: none;}

однако в Chrome (может еще где-то, тестировал только в Chrome и IE) эти эффекты совершенно не видны, т.к. при нажатии на кнопку она автоматичски подсвечивается голубой рамочкой. эта рамочка пропадает при нажатии на вторую кнопку, вторая соответственно подсвечивается.

подскажите пожалуйста, как убрать такое поведение браузера по умолчанию (а так же сходное поведение других браузеров).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите outline у input

```
input {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
input:focus,
input{
outline:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" />
```